# unknown attribute ruby on rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

So I've been trying to add a comments section for users to add their comments on Wedding venues. I've been following tutorials online on how to do this, however, I keep getting stuck on the same point.

The error:

```
Showing C:/Sites/Innovative_WeddingsLatest/app/views/comments/_form.html.erb where line #1 raised:

unknown attribute 'venue_id' for Comment.
Trace of template inclusion: app/views/venues/show.html.erb

Rails.root: C:/Sites/Innovative_WeddingsLatest

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/views/comments/_form.html.erb:1:in `_app_views_comments__form_html_erb___721803434_50744988'
app/views/venues/show.html.erb:32:in `_app_views_venues_show_html_erb___40167619_56734404'
```

Here is the code I have:

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
def create
    @venue = Venue.find(params[:venues_id])
    @comment = @venue.comments.create(params[:comment].permit(:name, :body))

    redirect_to venue_path(@venue)
end
```

Comment Model:

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :venues
end
```

Venue Model:

```
class Venue < ActiveRecord::Base
#check if user has left venue field blank, if so show error "cannot be blank"
validates :venue, :presence => {:message => "cannot be blank ..."}
#validates :name, presence: true, uniqueness: true

has_many :bookings
has_many :comments
end
```

Views/comments/_form.html.erb

```
<%= form_for([@venue, @venue.comments.build]) do |f| %>

<p>
    <%= f.label :name %>
</p>

<p>
    <%= f.label :body %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :body %>
</p>
<br>

<p>s
    <%= f.submit %>
</p>

<% end %>
```

Views/venues/show.html.erb

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>
<!-- when user clicks on "show" information of the specific venue is displayed on a single page --> 
</br>
</br>
</br>
</br>

<p>
  <strong>Venue:</strong>
  <%= @venue.venue %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>Description:</strong>
  <%= @venue.description %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>Price:</strong>
  <%= number_to_currency @venue.price, unit: "£" %>
</p>

<p>
    <%# if not @venue.img_url.blank? %>
      <strong>Img url:</strong>
      <%#= image_tag @venue.img_url, :size => "180x250" %>
    <%# else %>
        <%#= image_tag "no-image.jpg", :size => "180x250" %>
    <%# end %>
</p>

    <%= render 'comments/form' %>

<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_venue_path(@venue) %> |
<%= link_to 'Back', venues_path %>
```

The comments Migration:

```
    class CreateComments < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :comments do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.text :body
      t.references :venues

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

P.S. Sorry its the first time using this forums, so may not look the best :(

If anymore code is needed to solve the problem, let me know :D

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Could you show your schema.db file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your migration says `t.references :venues`. `t.references(model)` will here create a foreign key on table `t` with name "#{model}_id". This means that your foreign key is "venues_id", but what you want is "venue_id". Just singularize `t.references :venues` to `t.references :venue`.

This explains why the error says "unknown attribute 'venue_id' for Comment." Since you have "venues_id" instead of "venue_id", the venue_id attribute *doesn't exist*.

Make sure you rollback the migration (`rake db:rollback`) before rerunning `rake db:migrate`.

Comment: Thanks dude! It works perfectly! :D Can't believe I spent hours trying to fix this, should've posted earlier :P

Answer (score 0):

Please correct your association in comments model to `belongs_to :venue` also change the migration as per migration to `t.references :venue`
the field generated by migration in comments model would be 'venue_id' ans you are ready to go!!

Comment: Thanks! Just changed that first bit too, didn't realise :P

Answer (score 0):

Your migration says `t.references :venues`. `t.references(model)` will here create a foreign key on table t with name `#{model}_id`. This means that your foreign key is `venues_id`, but what you want is `venue_id`. Just singularize `t.references :venues` to `t.references :venue`.

This explains why the error says `unknown attribute 'venue_id' for Comment.` Since you have `venues_id` instead of `venue_id`, the `venue_id` attribute doesn't exist.

Make sure you rollback the migration (`rake db:rollback`) before rerunning `rake db:migrate`.

OR

You can simply change your migration table of `t.references` from `venues` to `venue` and run this command in your terminal `rake db:migrate:redo`.
This will change your schema table to the latest changes you did in your migration file.